# ORDER BY CASE CONDITIONAL BACKGROUND WORKING

Tags: sql, database

I was practicing SQL queries online when I came across this question:

Write a SQL query to find all the details of 1970 winners by the ordered to subject and winner name; but the list contain the subject Economics and Chemistry at last.

Below is the solution for the above question. But I cannot understand the below solution. I surfed the net to look for the understanding of the ORDER BY clause but could not find a clear explanation. I cannot understand what happens when we assign '1' or '0' and why do we do that. I want to know what actually happens when this query gets executed.

```
SELECT *
    FROM nobel_win
    WHERE year=1970 
    ORDER BY
     CASE
        WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END ASC,
     subject,
     winner;
```

Comment: dont'use UPPERCASE  ,,in web  It's like screaming

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first order condition is

```
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC
```

This sorts the complete result set first according to that condition.

So all records where `subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry')` get the order result `1` and all other the order result `0`. Then this gets ordered ASC (ascending) - so "0"-records come first, "1"-records second.

You could use any other number in the `case` statement. `2` and `3` or `20` and `93`. It is just an indicator what comes first.

In MySQL the result of a boolean condition automatically evaluates to `1` and `0`. So in MySQL you could reduce that to

```
order by subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry'),
         subject,
         winner;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically like

```
ORDER BY CASE (),
         SUBJECT,
         WINNER;
```

First, this statement will sort on the basis of **CASE** value then it will go for the **subject** and finally the **winner**
Value of CASE will be 0 if the value of the **subject** is not Economics or Chemistry else it will be 1